# How can I resolve this data type issue in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

There are a couple field types in my Elasticsearch cluster that I'm trying to change by moving the data from the original index to a new empty index using Python. I'm running into this error `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'mapper [stat_type] cannot be changed from type [keyword] to [text]')`. I don't understand how I get this error.

In my python dict, `stat_type` is a string and I've already set the new mapping for the new index like below. The new index is empty so I don't understand how it even registers as text. Thanks.

```
"stat_type" : {"type" : "keyword"}
```

Comment: Check with the data type you are sending and the existing mappings for the start type. mappings issue, data indexing is keyword type. You have to update the mappings and re-index the index. Let me know if you need help in reindexing. https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/6-steps-to-reindex-elasticsearch-data/

Comment: @JinnaBalu I tried reindexing but this did not resolve the issue. It appears as if the field data types didn't actually change even though the mapping did.

Comment: Can you change the mappings of the destination index, and create the new index. and reindex the data from the old index to the new index. this should resolve your issues. can you share the latest mappings of the index? if you still see the type value is the same, then ingestion will definitely fail.